# How to write an update statement with a combination PK table in Liquibase

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, primary-key, liquibase

Im not sure on the correct syntax. Any help would be appreciated

```
  <changeSet author="KN" id="TestForWhere">
        <update tableName="table_liqui">
            <column name="description" value="TEST"/>
            <where>country=: AND product=: AND productsize:=</where>
            <whereParams>
                <param valueNumeric="15" />
                <param value="aaa" />
                <param value="01" />
            </whereParams>
        </update>
    </changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

was able yo figure out, this worked for me:

```
<changeSet author="KN" id="TestForWhere">
    <update tableName="table_liqui">
        <column name="description" value="TEST"/>
        <where>company='15' and product='aaa' and product_size='1'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```